# ISR executes even though an interrupt is not triggered

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, c, isr, pointer

I am trying to implement a function queue scheduling system. INT1 is connected to a button and int1task causes an LED to flash.

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void);
TPrioQueue *queue = NULL;

void int1ISR() {
  if (debounce(&int1time)) // Checks if the interrupt is caused by switch bouncing
    enq(queue, (void*) int1task, 1);
}
```

Next, I execute the function in loop() by:

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void);

void loop(){
  funcptr func = (funcptr) deq(queue);
  if (func != NULL)
    (*func)(); // Stuck in a loop
}
```

For some reason, the LED keeps flashing even though I have not pressed the button. Why does this happen?

When I remove the line below, the ISR works properly.

```
enq(queue, (void*) int1task, 1)
```

The relevant sections of the code:

```
int debounce(unsigned long *debTimer) {
  unsigned long tmp = *debTimer;
  unsigned long currTime = millis();

  if ((currTime-tmp) > 500){
    *debTimer = currTime;
    return 1;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}

// Flashes LED at pin 6 five times at 2 Hz
void int1task(){
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    delay(250);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(1, int1ISR, RISING);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

[Code I used for the queue](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l6byqdd4r32rapd/AAD8Pxj7iiSoRjQvksr_U3o8a?dl=0)

Here is the [schematic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/51f8174815zycrg/schematic.pdf?dl=0) I am using:

[image]

Comment: If `debounce()` calls `millis()`, then it will not work, as `millis()` do not change within an ISR. Can yoi show the code of `debounce()`?

Comment: @jfpoilpret I have edited the code to call `millis()` only once. Similar to [https://community.spark.io/t/how-to-track-debouncing-in-an-interrupt-function/6918](https://community.spark.io/t/how-to-track-debouncing-in-an-interrupt-function/6918)

Comment: I don't see any code that toggles the led. I don't see any code initializing the interrupts.

Comment: Could you please also show the code of `int1task`? Without it it may be hard to diagnose your issue.

Comment: It seems the `int1task` is never removed from the queue, which would explain it's running forever. Where do the `enq` and `deq` come from? How was `queue` variable declared?

Comment: @jfpoilpret `enq` and `deq` are declared in a separate file. The `queue` is part of a struct called 'TPrioQueue'. I declare it `TPrioQueue *queue = NULL`

Comment: @jfpoilpret I do not understand why `int1task` is not being removed from the queue? I am dequeue-ing it in `loop()`

Comment: I suspect a concurrent access problem (by `loop()` and the ISR). I think you should post the code of `enq`, `deq` and also the `TPrioQueue` or a link to the code if it is a 3rd-party library.

Comment: @jfpoilpret [code for the queue](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l6byqdd4r32rapd/AAD8Pxj7iiSoRjQvksr_U3o8a?dl=0)

Comment: The queue has to be initialized with `makeQueue()`.

Comment: May be just a matter of style, but you may just write `if (func) func();`.

Comment: Your snippets are still lacking a few important lines of code: we would like to see the declaration of all variables: `queue`, `int1time`. Also, did you check what @EdgarBonet mentioned in a previous comment, ie initialize `queue` with `makeQueue()`? That seems a **real important** point here!

Comment: I just tested your sketch on my Uno: it works as expected provided the queue is properly initialized with `makeQueue()`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet The circuit works after adding `makeQueue()`

Answer (score 2):

After checking the queue functions that you use in your sketch, I see there is no protection against concurrent accesses in the `enq` and `deq` functions, which is a **must-have** if you use any of these functions from **within an ISR**.

I would suggest the simplest changes to these functions as follows:

```
void enq(TPrioQueue *queue, void *item, int priority)
{
    TPrioQEntry *newEntry=(TPrioQEntry *) malloc(sizeof(TPrioQEntry));

    if(newEntry != NULL)
    {
        newEntry->item=item;
        newEntry->prio=priority;
        newEntry->prev=NULL;
        newEntry->next=NULL;

        // Protect against concurrent accesses starting here
        uint8_t sreg = SREG;
        cli(); 
        if(queue->head==NULL)
            queue->head=newEntry;
        else
        {
            // Find insertion point.

            // First special case: Item at head has lower priority
            if(queue->head->prio > newEntry->prio)
            {
                // Insert item at the start of the queue.
                newEntry->next=queue->head;
                queue->head->prev=newEntry;
                queue->head=newEntry;
            }
            else
            {
                // Find your insertion point
                TPrioQEntry *trav= queue->head;

                while(trav->next!=NULL && trav->prio < newEntry->prio)
                    trav=trav->next;

                newEntry->prev=trav;
                newEntry->next=trav->next;
                if(trav->next != NULL)
                    trav->next->prev=newEntry;

                trav->next=newEntry;
            }
        }

        queue->itemCount++;
        // Protect against concurrent accesses stops here
        SREG = sreg;
    }   
}

void *deq(TPrioQueue *queue)
{
    // Protect against concurrent accesses starting here
    uint8_t sreg = SREG;
    cli(); 
    // Return NULL if queue is empty
    if(queue->head == NULL)
    {
        // Protect against concurrent accesses stops here
        SREG = sreg;
        return NULL;
    }

    void *ret=queue->head->item;
    TPrioQEntry *tmp=queue->head;

    if(queue->head->next!=NULL)
        queue->head->next->prev=NULL;

    queue->head=queue->head->next;
    free(tmp);

    queue->itemCount--;

    // Protect against concurrent accesses stops here
    SREG = sreg;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The above code did not work, the LED still kept flashing

Comment: If this still doesnot work, I suspect you may have some bad wiring or interferences somewhere in your circuit. Could you show a clear picture of your circuit? A schematoc would also be nice to have.

Comment: The simplest change would be to `#include <util/atomic.h>` and call `deq()` from an `ATOMIC_BLOCK`.

Comment: @jfpoilpret [schematic] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/51f8174815zycrg/schematic.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Isn't declaring some of the variables `volatile` required for this to work reliably?

Comment: I don't think so, because the only variables here are pointers; those pointers are not chnaged only the content they point to.

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not clearly mention nor show your wiring, it is possible the problem comes from here.

Barring **real concurrency issues** with your queue implementation, which I already mentioned in another answer, for which fixes have to be implemented anyway, there are two potential wiring problems in your circuit:

1. You use **INT1** interrupt; that means you must connect your button to **PIN 3** for a UNO, any other pin won't work.
2. You did not specify `pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP)` in your `setup()`, which means **you MUST use an external pullup resistor** to force a `HIGH` value, and connect the other pin of the button to `GND` (or conversely: put a pulldown resistor and wire the other pin to `5V`); otherwise, while the button is left unpressed, you will have a **floating input**, which means its value will vary randomly between HIGH and LOW, triggering your `int1ISR` many times when you don't expect it.

The simplest way to solve point 2 (floating input) is to use internal pullup resistors:

```
void setup() {  
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(1, int1ISR, RISING);   
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

and connect one button pin to Arduino PIN 3, and the other button pin to `GND`.

That will remove floating input and its consequences.

Answer (score 0):

ISRs have flags, typically an enable flag and a pending flag.

The enable flag needs to be set true for the interrupt to occur at all.

The pending flag is set when the interrupt event occurs.

Within the interrupt function, the pending flag must be cleared,

otherwise the the interrupt function will immediately be executed again (and again and again and ...)

Comment: AVR resets the interrupt flag once the ISR returns.

Comment: I am relatively new to arduino. Could you elaborate more about the flags? Are they like cli() and sei()?

Comment: My mistake, `INTFn` is cleared when the ISR is *executed*.